# Zapier pull Word Count of a given document and connect it with Google Sheets

Tags: zapier

Here is what I need help with:

I need to connect the Word Count of a given document with Google Sheets.

I tried this with the current settings that Zapier has, but apparently it doesn't pull the data from the Word Count.

I am struggling to find a solution for this. And I am wondering whether is just impossible with this platform because the data is not pulled, or there is something it could be done about it.

To give you some context, as why I would need this. It is because I run a ghostwriting company and I would need to track the progress of the projects. Having that information updating periodically in Google Sheets would be really helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I took a look and it seems like we're not pulling that right now. We've got an open feature request for the content. If you'd like, I can add your email to that request and you'll get notified if/when it gets fixed!

Comment: That would be great. Thank you David

Comment: My email is fabiancid90@gmail.com btw